# PyFolio - Zipline - Pandas version discprepancy

Tags: python, pandas, zipline

my first ever posting. I had `zipline 1.4.1` installed and working but then I attempted to install `PyFolio` using `pip install pyfolio`.

The PyFolio installation was successful, however, it ended up uninstalling my `pandas 0.22` version and installing `pandas 1.1.5` instead. Here is what I got:

```
Attempting uninstall: pandas
Found existing installation: pandas 0.22.0
Uninstalling pandas-0.22.0:
  Successfully uninstalled pandas-0.22.0
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
zipline 1.4.1 requires pandas<=0.22,>=0.18.1, but you have pandas 1.1.5 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed joblib-1.0.1 pandas-1.1.5 pyfolio-0.9.2 scikit-learn-0.24.2 seaborn-0.11.1 threadpoolctl-2.1.0
```

After this procedure, my zipline stopped working apparently because of the mismatch in the pandas version.

I tried to manually install the required pandas version using `pip install pandas==0.18.1` but that only gave a very long error message.

I am pretty clueless about what to do next. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved. I was using conda which was causing the dependencies issues. I also discovered (after posting the question above) that zipline has been discontinued (due to Quantopian folding) and has been replaced by zipline-trader. Zipline trader can be installed via pip which automatically solves all dependency issues.